# Failed to start Marathon in ubuntu

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

After install Marathon by `apt-get install marathon`, I failed to start Marathon by `service marathon start`; the command return process id but can not retrieve it by `ps`. And I can not get log of it.

If I run `/usr/bin/marathon`, I got following message `run_jar --zk zk://mesosStagingCompute9:2181/marathon --master zk://mesosStagingCompute9:2181/mesos`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which distribution do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This's because the default JRE is openjdk-7; need change the default JRE to openjdk-8.